# How to make multiple login forms with FOSUserBundle in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use Symfony 2.8.16 with FOSUserBundle 1.3.7 fos user management.
In "app/Resources", I have a "FOSUserBundle" folder to surcharge FOSUserBundle template with my template.
Currently, I have a login page on the mywebsite.com/login route.

On the other public pages of my website, I want to put a small login form at the top of each page.

How can I do this?

In app/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
index:
path:     /index
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:MyController:MyAction }

##################
# FOS User Bundle
##################
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

In app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/security/login.html.twig

```
{% extends ": MyLayout.html.twig" %}
{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-m-6">
      <input type="text" class="_username" id="_username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" placeholder="Email ou identifiant" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-m-6">
      <input type="password" class="_password" id="_password" name="_password" placeholder="Mot de passe" required="required" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form_action">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-default-outline" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}">Connexion</button>
    <div class="__sub">
      <label class="remember">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked> {{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
        <span class="separator">|</span>
        <a href="#" class="forgot">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a login form on your layout that submits in the fos login check :

```
    <form action="{{ path('fos_user_security_check') }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
        <input type="text" name="_username" />
        <input type="password" name="_password" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me" checked />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

You can, of course, change the style, add info and labels but this inputs must be there.

Comment: But I know that the login form generated by FosUserBundle contain a csrf token generated by FOSUserBundle. But this method doesn't let FOSUserBundle generated it's csrf token

Comment: FOSUserBundle checks the csrf token wih the intention "authenticate" so this will work

Comment: Is this the properly method to make multiple login form ?
And can I use the same method to the other FOSUserBundle form and views ?

Comment: I don't know for the other forms, I'm not that familiar with FOSUserBundle, sorry.